# Using ajax to pass pass values to controller from view in MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following in my Razor view file:

```
<button onClick="getFavouriteBooks()">Display Favourites</button>

<script>
function getFavouriteBooks() {
    var ids = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookIds"));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Favourites", "Home")',
        data: ids,
        dataType: "javascript"
    });
}
</script>
```

And in my Home Controller, this action:

```
public async Task<ViewResult> Favourites(string[] ids)
        {
            // var bookList = code that retrieves list of all books

            var favouriteBooks = bookList.Any(book => ids.Contains(book.Id));

            return View("Index", favouriteBooks);

        }
```

When user clicks 'Display Favourites' I get a 500 error for localhost/Home/Favourites. Can anyone help me see where I've gone wrong here?

Update: bookIds is an array of string Ids.

Comment: What do the server error logs tell you when it breaks? Note you aren't sending key/value, only value

Comment: @charlietfl I just get a 500 error 

POST https://localhost:5001/Home/Favourites 500 (Internal Server Error).

Yep, that's correct only intending to send the value which is an array of string Ids

Comment: That is a client side error. You need to look in server side error log file

Comment: As for "only intending to send value" ... that's not how a default POST request works. Key/value pairs are sent

Comment: it means that the string[] ids is empty.

Comment: Could you show pls how you put bookids in a localstorage?

Answer (score 0):

So I think there is a couple of things going on here.

I am assuming it’s a “get” request not a “post” request. Since you want to display the books. If you want to “get” all that match an id the easiest way would be to get the total response and loop through it. If it is just for a small project if it’s serious you want to want to change your SQL to find where ID.

But assuming you just want assistance with the JavaScript.

First of all if you put your javascript in line like that you need to also handle the response in line which isn't going to be syntactically very friendly. After all we are not writing php.

The second point about async functions is that you need a response which will happen asynchronously so need to await. Also need to handle the promise

I have simplified what I think is the solution here to use fetch instead of ajax to avoid all the jquery and Ajax setup with code pen but the logic should be there for you to follow up.

https://codepen.io/sijbc/pen/qBRrgBG?editors=1111

```
  fetch('https://api.github.com/users')
     .then(res => res.json())//response type
     .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Also found this article which would be worth checking out

https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/ajax-async-callback-promise-e98f8074ebd7

Answer (score 0):

Update `data` with added `contentType` in ajax call as below and check again

```js
function getFavouriteBooks() {
    var ids = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookIds"));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Favourites", "Home")',
        // jQuery refers below mentioned contentType to serialize data in JSON format
        // Without this, serialization will be url encoded string
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        // Assuming ids as a array of strings
        // data to be an object that holds Action methods parameters as it's properties
        // Stringify object before assigning to data
        data: JSON.stringify({
            ids: ids
        }),
        dataType: "javascript"
    });
}
```